# How to read Server disk space details via sas code

Tags: cmd, sas, wmic

Here I need to read the details of my windows server disk utilization from sas code.

```
Below thing I want to achieve(using SAS code):
C:>wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption
Caption  FreeSpace     Size
C:       42665123840   157181538304
D:       23106641920   32209104896
E:       218217590784  279169724416
```

With SAS, I tried using X command, but it works when we only need to command OS and doesn't care of response.
Whereas in this case I want to create report/dataset out of the response coming from OS.

```
data _null_;
 x 'wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption';
run;
```

Comment: So where exactly does windows [`batch-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) fit into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PIPE filename engine. Then you can read the output of the command as if it was a file.

```
data want;
  infile 'wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption' pipe firstobs=2;
  input disk $ freespace size ;
run;
```